# Tangent Planes and Surfaces (Calc 3)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

I am wondering if I am on the right track for the following question:

Find *a* for the plane $x+y+z=-1$ so that it is a tangent plane to the surface $z=x^2+ay^2$

I figured since you are given a tangent plane and a surface that you would need to parameterize the surface using the following equation:
r(u,v)=x(u,v)**i**+y(u,v)**j**+z(u,v)**k**. You would next derive in terms of u and v so you would have the derivative of u(r(u)) and derivative of v(r(v)), which you would then use the cross product on r(u) X r(v).

Would this be able to work even though I am solving for the variable *a*?

Comment: Hints: What is the normal vector of the given plane?  Recall that the gradient gives the normal vector of the tangent plane of a surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuition: a tangent plane intersects a convex surface (e.g. a paraboloid) in exactly one point. If that's true, and substituting one equation into the other, we seek the only solution $(x,y)$ which satisfies $x^2+x+(ay^2+y+1)=0$. Applying the formula for the roots of a quadratic equation (twice) and demanding a single root, I got the condition for $a=\frac{1}{3}$.